# Compute $\|T\|$ when $D (T)$ is endowed with $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=\{f\in C[0,1]:f (0)=0\}$. Define $$T:X \to \mathbb R$$
$$T_f=\int_0^1 f (t)dt$$
Compute $\|T\|$ when $X$ is endowed with $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

By approximating, I have $$|T_f| \leq\int_0^1 |f (t)|dt \leq \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f (t)| \int_0^1 dt = ||f||_{\infty}$$
Thus, $\|T\| \leq 1$.

My challenge is to show $\|T\| \geq 1$. To do this I have to find an $f \in X$ such that $\|f\| \leq 1$ and $|T_f| = 1$. Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: I would give as hint: take a small $\epsilon>0$ and try to find an $f_{\epsilon}$ such that $|T_{f_{\epsilon}}|\geq 1-\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an $f$ won't exist. You would like to take $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$, but we require $f(0) = 0$.  Hence we approximate $f$ by a sequence of $f_n \in X$, in particular something like

$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
nx & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
1 & x \geq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$$

You can show $\lvert T(f_n) \rvert \to 1$ which will show that $\lVert T \rVert \geq 1$.

Comment: What justifies the fact that such an $f$ doesn't  exist?

Comment: Such an $f$ would require $\lvert f(x) \rvert = 1$ almost everywhere, which then then by continuity would force $f$ to be constantly 1 or constantly -1. This then wouldn't start at 0.

Comment: Thanks boss! So, not in most cases can one find such functions.

Comment: Why does $f_n$ converge to something in $C[0,1]$? I mean if it's Cauchy, it should, even though it's really non-intuitive. But is it Cauchy?

Comment: @stressedout It doesn't converge to something in $C[0, 1]$, the sequence is not Cauchy with respect to the supremum norm

Comment: Good. Because I was starting to doubt my eyes. So, you're just using the fact that $|T(f_n)| \to 1$? Nothing else? Why is that enough to conclude that $\|T\| \geq 1$?

Comment: @stressedout Yes, remember $\lvert T \rvert = \sup \{ \lvert T(f) \rvert : \lVert f \rVert \leq 1\}$ is defined as a supremum. The supremum does not (and indeed in this case will not) be achieved.

Comment: Yes. So, you're technically saying that if $\|T\| \leq 1-\frac{1}{n}$, you can find $f_N$ such that $|T(f_N)| > 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Cool. (+1)